# How to use win32::WriteFile when there is possible fail option?

Tags: c#, c++

I using the win32 method 'WriteFile' to do some work in C# ( version .net 4.0 ) 
I need to wait till the method will finish the task and to do it i using 'WaitForSingleObject' .

But there is some cases that the method 'WriteFile' is fail ==> so for this case i gave the 'WaitForSingleObject' 30 seconds time-out.

But after this 30 seconds i get off the scope of the method 'WriteFile' => there if the GC will run the objects that i gave as arguments in the method 'WriteFile' will be collected and when this happened i get a crash !!! -

I checked the dump and its saying the i have memory corruption. 
When i remove the line of 'WriteFile' the crash is not appears.

How to solve it ?!
I can't make the variables of the 'WriteFile' method to be global and i must leave them as local variables.

The code

```
      public void foo(byte[] bufferToWrite)
      {
          unsafe
          {

          NativeOverlapped overlapped = new NativeOverlapped()
          {
                EventHandle = eventHandle,
                OffsetLow   = ( int )( s       & 0xffffffff ),
                OffsetHigh  = ( int )( s >> 32 & 0xffffffff )
          };

          GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc( bufferToWrite, GCHandleType.Pinned );
          IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr( ( void* )gch.AddrOfPinnedObject() );

          bResult = WriteFile( handle, ptr, length, ref bytesWritten, &overlapped );
          if( bResult == ERROR_SUCCESS == || bResult == ERROR_IO_PENDING )
          {
                dwResult = WaitForSingleObject( EventHandle, 30000 );
          }
          }
 }
```

Comment: Please make up your mind. You tagged it C#/C++, talk about C# in the first paragraph, and post C++ code. What exactly is it you're asking about? C# and C++ are two very different languages.

Comment: @KenWhite: It's `unsafe` C# code.

Comment: CancelIo() is required to abort the overlapped I/O request.  Or CloseHandle().  Not sure why you are writing code like, the FileStream class supports this too.

Comment: @dtb: Thanks for the info. :) I didn't catch that; there's absolutely no need for unsafe code here, as Hans mentions. I wouldn't have considered using it here.

Comment: Guys ... forgot to copy..paste the "unsafe" - and lets leave the closeHandles please ... lest focus on the problem because i'm know about the closeHandles and i just copy..paste the main part of the code.

Comment: See Raymond Chen's posts about this very thing: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/02/10123392.aspx. See also part 2 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/03/10124060.aspx) and part 3 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/04/10124610.aspx).